# Discord.js bot with cluster responding several times

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a discord bot done with discord.js and I decided to use cluster on it, but it is responding several times, can someone help me?

Comment: Hi mate, welcome to SO. If you want us to help you, please provide us with your code and also explain the error as well. :D

Comment: Can you edit your post to show your message event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what it looks like, cluster is a way to multithread nodejs, so the same request is getting passed to multiple threads and they all respond with the same message. Make sure the message only gets passed to one thread

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js have it owner to take advantage of multithread is call sharding [Docs it here](https://discordjs.guide/sharding/)

Try this instead of using cluster for multithread